# NodeJS - How can I prevent .query() from overwriting data fields with the same name?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM teams JOIN users 
AS user_a ON teams."userIds"[1] = user_a.id 
JOIN users AS user_b ON teams."userIds"[2] = user_b.id
```

I have this SQL query which basically displays data from a table called "teams", along with the user information being gathered from the table "users" that make up that team. However, when I run this query through NodeJS, only user_b data comes through because I'm assuming user_A data is being overwritten due to the columns having the same names from the "user" table.

How can I get both user_A data and user_B data to come through?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the [`rowMode` option](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#row-mode) to stop `node-postgres` from collecting results in object and keep the results as an array of values.

```js
const res = await client.query({ ...query, rowMode: 'array'})
```

You can also explicitly rename the fields you need to read from your tables.

```
SELECT 
  teams.*,
  user_a.id AS aId, 
  user_b.id AS bId -- You can explicitly rename the fields
FROM teams JOIN users 
AS user_a ON teams."userIds"[1] = user_a.id 
JOIN users AS user_b ON teams."userIds"[2] = user_b.id
```